# Nattable for netbeans RCP application

Tags: netbeans, eclipse-rcp, nattable

We have been using nattable in our eclipse RCP desktop application.
Now we are switching from eclipse RCP to netbeans RCP and want to use nattable in netbeans. I have been searching the nattable support for netbeans but was unable to get solid proof that nattable are supported by netbeans IDE or not?
Can someone please point me out in right direction?

Answer (score 2):

NatTable is currently built on top of SWT and JFace. AFAIK Netbeans is using Swing and JavaFX as UI toolkits. So at the time writing this, there is no native support for NatTable in NetBeans.